# Is there a similar expression to "pearl clutching" without the gender implications

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I generally like the expression "[clutching their pearls](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/clutches+their+pearls)" as an expression of exaggerated shock or scandal. However, its origins in women's jewelry gives it a sexist bent that I'd rather avoid. Is there a similar phrase with the same general implications, but without the gendered lens?

Comment: The ridicule implied by the original expression, towards the person reacting thus, is specific not only to the female sex but also to a wealthy and leisured class, like Boston Brahmins. Do you want to retain that class angle, too?

Comment: I think so, yes. The current state of use seems to be largely a division of class/moral sensibility/age, and the sexist implication is incidental. I still want to highlight the former, while removing the latter.

Comment: Although the usual image is of a shocked woman doing the pearl-clutching, we found a couple of references in Google Books to male clutching, including a strange one from Arabian Antic, a 1938 book by Ladislas Farago about Jews in the Arab world.

In a chapter on Yemen, Farago describes a rabbi whose “skinny fingers clutched the pearls of a rosary” while “his withered lips sucked the tube of a gigantic” hookah.  https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2012/02/pearl-clutch.html

Comment: This is a situation in need for a word, I wrote up the answer **first world problems** however I have temporarily deleted it as, I think it is inadequate in regard to *overstated alarm* even if it catches some of the class aspects

Comment: To help others along, I can hear the WSJ referring to  "histrionic concerns in bedroom communities" or something.  "overreactions in sheltered zip-codes" ?  **shelter-shock** gets some of it across, but a bit less elite and a bit too much notion of un-metropolitan .. exact opposite in some nuances

Comment: @Tom22 I think you've definitely got the right implication. All that's missing now is pithiness.

Comment: I'm really close to a good answer .. the second word is on the tip of my tongue but I'm thinking **privileged paranoia**  .. that is fairly pithy but I think there is a word with the equal zeitgeist of "privilege" for the paranoia part.

Comment: **privileged palpitations** perhaps - it's a bit too stilted in the WSJ style of self-parody.

Comment: Selective or faux outrage

Comment: And there was me thinking the expression referred to footballers shielding their testicles!

Comment: John Lennon said something once at a Royal Command Performance that the Beatles appeared  ' the people in the cheaper seats, would you please clap your hands. and the rest of you if you would just rattle your jewellery!' This was to show appreciation though, not angst... https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=rZcKTGtVhsA

Comment: Wondering if you could say 'clutching their gods' referring to journey of the magii. https://allpoetry.com/The-Journey-Of-The-Magi i also found 'clutching their guns and bibles'. And I thought of 'clutching their bills' or 'clutching their stocks'.

Comment: I guess *moral outrage* is pithy and with a similar meaning, but it doesn't conjure an image in the same way that "pearl clutching" does.

Answer (score 2):

Economist and NY Times columnist Paul Krugman often uses "shocked, *shocked*" to characterize elites who overstate their disapproval... his usage contains more than a hint of a sneer at disingenuous hypocrisy, but it has the benefit of avoiding a gendered connotation.

> "I see that the Washington Post editorial board is shocked, *shocked*
>   to discover that the incoming Republicans aren’t serious about deficit
>   reduction. Who could have suspected?"

Comment: I like this usage a lot as a predicate adjective. It doesn't translate as well to a more abstract verb usage (e.g. "pearl clutching" vs. "person X clutched their pearls"), but that isn't strictly necessary. Rephrasing can largely get around that.

Comment: FYI, this use derives from the movie "Casablanca". Renault says "I am shocked- shocked- to find that gambling is going on in here!"