# Usage of the phrase “I clutched my pearls”, esp. for males?

Tags: etymology, idioms, phrase-usage

I came across with a phrase, “clutch one’s pearls” in the headline of the Hill (January 6).
It reads :

> “Dem lawmaker: ‘Kind of odd’ for GOP to be ‘**clutching their pearls**’
>   over profane call to impeach Trump” and followed by the following
>   paragraph: Rep. David Cicilline (D-R.I) on Sunday scoffed at the
>   controversy surrounding Rep. Rashida Tlaib’s (D-Mich.) profane vow to
>   impeach President Trump, accusing Republicans critical of the freshman
>   lawmaker’s comment of hypocrisy.

I was unfamiliar with the phrase, “clutch one’s pearls,” and I found the definition of 
“clutch your pearls” in Cambridge Dictionary as follows:

> Disapproving to behave as if you are very shocked, especially when you show more shock than you really feel in order to show that you think something is morally bad.

Google Ngram doesn’t accommodate neither clutch your pearls or one’s pearls.

So my questions:

1. From around what time this phrase started to be in use?
2. What is the origin of this phrase?
3. Is it a popular phrase?
4. Can a man – males seldom wear a pearl necklace - use this phrase in such a way as, “I clutched my pearls when I heard Tom was fired from his office yesterday”?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/428671/is-there-a-similar-expression-to-pearl-clutching-without-the-gender-implicatio

Comment: I don't think anybody would say "I clutched my pearls". It is one of those expressions which convey a judgment on the person said to be doing it .

Comment: Neither men nor women would be likely to ever say, “I clutched my pearls when…”: this expression is exclusively (or at least almost exclusively) used in progressive or non-finite constructions. It’s also more used to describe _other_ people than oneself because it’s somewhat belittling. You might hear, “Tom getting fired had Sheila clutching her pearls”. You might also hear it used to describe a man, though it tends to carry sexist overtones then: its pejorativeness makes it imply that he’s weak/over-sensitive/anything else stereotypically seen as negative female traits.

Comment: I am male and there was at least one occasion when I should have said it.  A friend of mine was working for the designer, Vivienne Westwood and he had a lot of her jewelry at his place.  One day I picked up a necklace featuring 12 drop pearls and 12 drop garnets and we popped across the street to the French bakery to buy some bread.  The woman at the counter took one look at me in my pearls and quipped to her colleague - "Peut-etre il part au grand voyage".  Now if that's not grounds for clutching ones pearls, then tell me what is.

Comment: @UserEpsilon Yes, well, I fail to see how this adds anything here. Why would going on a long journey mean you wear your pearls? I guess in the old days people went on ocean voyages, and in first class wore all their finery. The baker's quip in no way implied she was looking to grab them....so why would you clutch them?

Comment: Generally, one says this of others. Especially, men about men. It's like in the armed services where the sergeants call the soldiers "ladies". Same idea.

Comment: This sounds like _euphemism_, especially from a male perspective ;)

Comment: I wonder whether this is one of those ideas which we are all familiar with in fiction but which doesn't actually happen in real life. Like ostriches putting their heads in the sand, or people turning white with shock.

Answer (score 9):

As noted in the following article by [Grammarphobia](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2012/02/pearl-clutch.html):

> People have been literally clutching their pearls in shock or otherwise for a long time. Here, for example, is a citation from a 1910 issue of the Chambers Journal, a weekly magazine that published fiction and nonfiction:
>
> - “Without being aware that I had stirred, I found myself close to the table. I drew a gasping breath, and my hand went out without any conscious volition and clutched the pearls.”

But the phrase itself became popular years later mainly as a mocking metaphor, meaning “being ostentatiously shocked by something not all that shocking,” especially if the “shock” was feigned or reflected outdated social prejudices:

> - a gay character on the Fox TV show ***In Living Color*** is responsible for the earliest example of the usage mentioned in discussions over the last six months on the American Dialect Society’s Linguist List.
> - In an April 15, 1990, sketch, the flamboyant cultural critic Blaine Edwards (played by Damon Wayans) gushes over how daring the producers were to cast a male actor as the female lead in Dangerous Liaisons.
> - When told that Glenn Close is actually a woman, Edwards squeals in mock shock and says, ***“Well, clutch the pearls! What a sneaky thing to do.”***

As suggested in the following [extract](https://slate.com/human-interest/2012/01/pearl-clutching-how-the-phrase-became-a-feminist-blog-cliche.html), the expression is now dated and its usage has largely declined in recent years:

> Judging from the instances of “clutch the pearls” and “pearl clutching” that I found in a Nexis search, ***the expression showed up only periodically through about 2004, almost always as a pun about wealthy women and literal pearls.*** Take a 2000 episode of World News Tonight in which co-anchor Alison Stewart said there was “a lot of pearl-clutching going on” in the high-end auction business following accusations of criminal price-fixing. ***The expression then went largely dormant.*** There are only 16 Google results for “pearl clutching” between Jan. 1, 2000, and Jan. 1, 2004, though it did appear in a 2003 academic work called Speaking in Queer Tongues: Globalization and Gay Language.

(https://slate.com)

Answer (score 8):

The phrase “clutch one’s pearls” is always used derisively or sarcastically. Basically, it’s a put-down. It suggests a hysterical woman on the verge of a swoon. Moreover, it has an added flavor of an old-time caricature from movies of a bygone generation. Cf. Margaret Dumont in a Marx Brothers movie from the ‘30s:

[image]

You see Dumont on the left, prim and proper, ready to play the straight role to the comedians’ shenanigans. That might include shock, outrage, or even obliviousness. She might even fall on a couch clutching her pearls.

A man would never say this about himself, except to make a self-deprecatory joke. To say it about him would be tantamount to calling him a hysterical old lady (which is offensive not only to him but to elderly women as well). To say it about a woman would be a sexist put down.

Any way you slice it, utilizing that image to describe anybody is extremely derogatory.

Comment: Happy new year! It's a pretty long time to hear from you. Thanks for an intrguing input. I'm still well with this site.

Comment: "males seldom wear a pearl necklace" -- Er, no, Mike, don't make that comment you were thinking of!

Comment: For the record, the expression is not really about oneself. So, either a man or woman can say it. That said, it is always sarcastic. And also somewhat macho....

Comment: @YoichiOishi: 明けましておめでとうございます!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: What does that comment have to do with my answer? Did you mean to address the question, not my answer?

Comment: Pearl necklace has also another meaning...in pornography. I think Michael H was only teasing himself :)

Comment: The accusation of sexism here - let alone the idea that using the phrase is specifically derogatory to *elderly* women as a class - seems bizarre to me. Wearing necklaces isn't something especially correlated with age, as far as I know, so I don't really see why age even comes into it. And in any case, I don't see how use of the term is derogatory to any demographic; negative references to a negative behaviour aren't automatically bigotry just because there's a stereotype associating the behaviour with some demographic group.

Comment: I had always assumed that this was in reference to rosary beads.

Comment: Rare for rosary beads to be pearls.

Answer (score 3):

- From around what time this phrase started to be in use?

  It now appears in [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/34894?rskey=0OmW8W&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) as a draft addition:

> - Draft additions June 2018
> - Chiefly U.S. to clutch one's pearls and variants: to react with shock    or dismay, esp. in response to something considered immoral,
>   underhand, or vulgar. Frequently ironic or humorous.

- What is the origin of this phrase?

The OED cites this sentence as in its draft.  It is dated 1990:

> 1990   F. Ajaye et al. In Living Color (transcribed from TV programme)
> 1st Ser. Episode 1   Clutch the pearls, what a sneaky thing to do!

- Is it a popular phrase?

It appears to be increasing in popularity and usage.

- Can a man – males seldom wear a pearl necklace - use this phrase in
  such a way as, “I clutched my pearls when I heard Tom was fired from
  his office yesterday”?

[image]

It's gender neutral as it is a metaphor for  humorously or ironically "shocked!" In the cited article, the entire Republican party is accused of **clutching their pearls!**

Comment: This answer is wrong as shown by the other answers. The phrase is far older than the suggested origin of 1990.

Comment: @Bent so edited. tks

Comment: The answer is not wrong. It's used by media pundit types discussing politics. To react with shock or dismay is somewhat recent. It's usually used by one person describing another's reaction to something. One doesn't go round using it in the first person generally. Though a humorous-minded person might.

Comment: Reading the whole of @Bent's comment, he's saying it's wrong *in one aspect*, i.e. the dating. The video clip, featuring a fairly obvious single entendre, is less helpful as it's rude joke is *not* helping to elucidate the original meaning :o)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old topic/question, but I feel like, it did cover pretty much everything in a few different posts, the entirety of it from someone who is confident in its usage and its origin. And that person is me.

"clutch your pearls", "clutch her pearls", "clutch his pearls", "clutch my pearls",  this expression is appropriate with any pronoun, under any given past present or future tense, as well as plural. Oh and less often said these days "clutch the pearls" but that's how Damon Wayons said it on "In loving color" which is as far as the internet will go, the origin of the modern, humorous/playfully derogatory use is concerned.

Now, the key to this phrase, before you know anything else is: when saying this expression you do so in your best impression of an exaggerated, older, rich ($), Victorian woman. Think white hair, a fur of some kind and if course a pearl necklace. The reason she's clutching her pearls is because something has suprised her in a way that only she finds threatening. And being that this ficticious character/stereotype is known for being very materialistic and judgemental. So, of course, at the first sign of anything not very threatening, she clutches hold of her pearls like her life depends on it.

Also for those who aren't aware; in America long ago it was quite trendy for rich white Victorian women to wear pearls.

Comment: This appears to comment on and repeat information given in other answers.  Answers benefit from citing researched sources.  Please take a moment to [tour] the site and see the [help] for how to [edit].

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, Janus Bahs Jacquet wrote:

> Nei­ther men nor women would be likely to ever say, “I clutched my 
>   pearls when…”: this ex­pres­sion is ex­clu­sively (or at least 
>   al­most ex­clu­sively) used in pro­gres­sive or non-fi­nite
>   con­struc­tions. It’s also more used to de­scribe *other* peo­ple
>   than one­self be­cause it’s some­what be­lit­tling. You might hear,
>   “Tom get­ting fired had Sheila clutch­ing her pearls”. You might
>   also hear it used to de­scribe a man, though it tends to carry
>   sex­ist over­tones then: its pe­jo­ra­tive­ness makes it im­ply
>   that he’s weak/over-sen­si­tive/any­thing else stereo­typ­i­cally
>   seen as neg­a­tive fe­male traits.

And in another comment, Lambie wrote:

> Gen­er­ally, one says this of oth­ers. Espe­cially, men about men. It's like in the armed ser­vices where the sergeants call the sol­diers "ladies". Same idea.

Comment: So, I'm interested in what's you are gonna say.

Comment: @YoichiOishiI had not planned to say any­thing my­self. I just wanted to pre­serve both their re­lated com­ments to ren­der them find­able by searches, be­cause al­though they don’t ad­dress your first three sub­ques­tions, they do ad­dress your fourth and fi­nal sub­ques­tion, the one about whether men could say it and why. It was the most in­ter­est­ing of your set of four, or so it seemed to me, so these seemed worth pre­serv­ing. Should ei­ther au­thor care to de­velop their own an­swer, I shall gladly delete this post, but un­til such time, it is more search­able this way.

Comment: *"Gen­er­ally, one says this of oth­ers. Espe­cially, men about men."* - It's definitely something normally said about others, but in my experience it is not said especially by or about men, it is frequently used regardless of gender.

Answer (score -4):

I find the many erudite answers compelling, but wrong.

I believe the meaning is much more vulgar. I think it is a euphemism for a fearful attempt to protect a man's genitals (the family jewels) from harm, or for anyone to fearfully protect one's wealth or status (pearl jewelry) from loss or theft.

It suggests that something has triggered a fight or flight response, or a knee jerk reaction.

Comment: "I believe" is not compelling evidence :) Besides, as you correctly pointed out, men's testicles are sometimes referred to as "the family jewels". I think, "squeezing" or "grabbing" are the more common collocations

Comment: That's the meaning I assumed when I saw the question!  Which indicates that 1) the phrase isn't at all common (in the UK at least); and 2) its real meaning isn't obvious if you don't already know it.

Comment: Do you know of any references to this interpretation? If you had a source, it would lend your answer more credibility.

Comment: One does NOT show disapproval by protecting their genitals.

Comment: I doubt any living man would compare their "jewels"  to that of pearls. Although spherical, pearls tend to be quite small...

Comment: This answer really made me laugh. But why would anyone call them..a necklace?